# i dont know why am getting a false value

Tags: excel, if-statement

Am trying to get a value best on my if conditions but every time my the value in Cell GV2 is 40 and above i get a false yet i want it to be DIV 2
here is the code

=IF(AND(GV2="DIV 4",GD2>=60),"U",IF(AND(GV2="DIV 4",GD2<=59),"DIV 4",IF(AND(GV2="DIV 3",GD2>=52),"DIV 4",IF(AND(GV2="DIV 3",GD2<=51),"DIV 3",IF(AND(GV2="DIV 2",GD2>=45),"DIV 3",IF(AND(GV2="DIV 2",GD2<=44),"DIV 2",IF(AND(GV2="DIV1",GD2>=33),"DIV 2",IF(AND(GV2="DIV 1",GD2<=32),"DIV 1"))))))))

Comment: I suggest you split this out into single tests as most of your questions about if() with and() come down to faulty logic.

Comment: Also in the last line you show you are testing for "DIV1" while in the next test it is "DIV 1"

Comment: but i want to use one if statement with AND function is it ok if you show me how i can do it in your own view

Comment: So split it out into single tests, then find which bit causes your error, THEN you can put it back together. Also I pointed out an error that you seem to have ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, corrected the typos and it works:
[image]

Note, you are testing cell GD2 for the number and cell GV2 for the text as per your IF() statement, but in your question text you seem to be confused.